# Access a CSS3 property-value from CSS3 code itself

Tags: css, properties, attributes

I have a question which I can't find answered Googling around.
I would like to know if there's a way to access elements attributes from CSS3 code itself (CSS for simplicity). I'm not looking for other solutions that make use of JavaScript or CSS classes and ids because I know well how to solve the problem in that way. My question is very specific.

As an example, let's say that I have the following CSS code:

```
body { color: black;}
p { color: green;}
```

and suppose that I want to set the `color` CSS attribute value of a specific tag/class/id to be the same as `<body>` by referencing it and not just placing a simple `color:black` specification. In other word, I would like to have **something like this**:

```
.mySpecificP { color: body.color;}
```

The HTML code should be something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body { color: black;}
            p { color: green;}
            .mySpecificP { color: body.color;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This is a green paragraph.</p>
        <p class="mySpecificP">This is a black paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I'm using `<p>` just as an example. I'm wondering if there's a solution to the `body.color` pseudo-code I used in the CSS definition of `mySpecificP` class.

Comment: No you can't do this with vanilla CSS. You'd have to use a CSS pre-processor like Sass to do this, and then compile it into actual CSS before the browser can parse it.

Comment: It hurts.. :p there isn't a way to achieve this using `inherit` or something similar? Perhaps a `color:root`?

Comment: Children can inherit *some* properties from their parents.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [currentColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentColor_keyword) like so:

```
body { 
  color: black;
}

p { 
  color: green;
}

.mySpecificP { 
  color: currentColor;
}
```

Basically `currentColor` contains elements inherited color value (in this case from `body`) and can also be used on other properties like `background-color`, `border-color`, etc.

[**Working example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjqVNE)

All relatively modern browsers [are supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=currentcolor)